# GeoBubbleChart Colors

Tags: geographics

I'm struggling to find a way to change the default background color of a state, say the Netherlands, when using GeoBubbleChart.

When using GeoGraphics this is pretty easy. For example,

```
GeoGraphics[{
  EdgeForm[Black],
  FaceForm[Black],
  Polygon[GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Belgium"], "PrincipalArea"]],
  Polygon[
   GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Netherlands"], "PrincipalArea"]],
  Polygon[
   GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Luxembourg"], "PrincipalArea"]]},
 GeoScaleBar -> "Metric",
 ImageSize -> Full,
 GeoBackground -> None,
 GeoRange -> {{49, 53.6}, {2, 7.5}}
 ]
```

However, how to obtain the same result with GeoBubbleChart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Carl's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216862/52) is most likely what you are looking for as it limits what is in the background. But, if you are interested in changing how the background countries look, I would suggest using one of the variants of [`GeoStyling["CountryBorders"]`](http://wolfram.com/xid/0en0cz1no-w2khar). For example,

```
d = {Entity["Country", "Belgium"] -> Quantity[11429336, "People"], 
   Entity["Country", "Netherlands"] -> Quantity[17035938, "People"], 
   Entity["Country", "Luxembourg"] -> Quantity[583455, "People"]};

GeoBubbleChart[d,
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[
   {"CountryBorders", "Land" -> Gray, "Ocean" -> White, "Border" -> Black}],
 GeoRange -> GeoGroup[d[[All, 1]]]
]
```

[image]

The additional options also apply to `"Coastlines"`, too.

Comment: Beat me to it! :) `GeoStyling[]` is a surprisingly flexible thing.

Comment: @J.M. the only complication is `Dated` which isn't working correctly (at this point) with the added options. But, yes, `GeoStyling` is a very, very nice thing.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use `Show` to combine the two:

```
d = {Entity["Country", "Belgium"] -> Quantity[11429336, "People"], 
   Entity["Country", "Netherlands"] -> Quantity[17035938, "People"], 
   Entity["Country", "Luxembourg"] -> Quantity[583455, "People"]};

Show[
 GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Black], 
   Polygon[GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Belgium"], "PrincipalArea"]],
    Polygon[
    GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Netherlands"], "PrincipalArea"]], 
   Polygon[GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Luxembourg"], 
     "PrincipalArea"]]}, GeoScaleBar -> "Metric"],
 GeoBubbleChart[d, GeoBackground -> None, 
  GeoRange -> {{49, 53.6}, {2, 7.5}}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Annoyingly, this doesn't work in older versions of *Mathematica*.

Comment: @J.M. define "older". What versions?

Comment: @rcollyer, this seems to be broken in 11.2; at least it seems to be okay in 12 and 12.1.

Comment: @J.M. makes sense. I think `Show` support was added in 11.3.

Answer (score 5):

```
countries = Entity["Country", #] & /@ {"Netherlands", "Belgium", "Luxembourg"};
populations = EntityValue[countries, "Population"];
```

We can also use `GeoRegionValuePlot` to style individual country polygons

```
grvp = GeoRegionValuePlot[Thread[countries -> Range[Length@countries]], 
   GeoRange -> {{49, 53.6}, {2, 7.5}}, 
   ColorFunction -> (Opacity[.5, ColorData[97][#]] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> None];
```

and `Show` `grvp` with `GeoBubbleChart` using the option `GeoBackground -> None`:

```
Show[grvp, 
 GeoBubbleChart[Thread[countries -> populations], 
  ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[1], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  GeoRange -> {{49, 53.6}, {2, 7.5}}, GeoBackground -> None], 
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use `Image @ grvp` with the option `GeoBackground`:

```
GeoBubbleChart[Thread[countries -> populations], 
 ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[1], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 GeoRange -> {{49, 53.6}, {2, 7.5}}, 
 GeoBackground -> {"Image", Image @ grvp}]
```

[image]